# How to grep substring on a specific column

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file with values in $4 as shown below:

```
Deaf, a 603622 (3), Auto dom; 153650 (3), Autosomal dominant; Fechtner (4)
cancer, somatic, 114500 (2); Rubinstein-Taybi syndrome 2, 613684 (3)
```

$4 has multiple delimiters: space, comma, semicolon

I would need to extract the rows by matching regex (2) or (3) or (4). For instance, i tried to match and grep rows with $4 having (2) using the awk command:

```
awk -F "\t" '{if ($4 ~ "(2)") print $0;}'
```

and

```
awk -F "\t" '{if ($4 ~ "2") print $0;}'
```

these 2 solutions greps everything with 2 or '(' or ')'

and

```
awk -F "\t" '{if ($4 = "(2)") print $0;}'
```

prints (2) in $4

Any suggestions to make it work would be helpful.

Comment: Over and over again, please provide a [mcve]. Otherwise, we will keep editing our answers after your comments.

Comment: In this particular case, the answer the OP has accepted as correct doesn't come close to answering the question that was asked. Since the OP has accepted it as the right answer we must assume that the posted question doesn't come close to describing what the OP actually wants to do. The point is - if you got here because you have the same question as the one posted, do not think that the accepted answer here is the answer to that question as it's not so find or ask a new question.

Comment: I do not understand why the OP is not close to the answer!! I have asked that i need to match '(2)' or '(3)'  i.e. a number including the braces and the accepted solution does it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear, With lots of assumptions this is one possible solution. I am not sure if this is what exactly you asked for.

## case-I:

```
  #If no integer mentioned inside (),   

   cat sample
   Deaf, a 603622 (s), Auto dom; 153650 (s), Autosomal dominant; Fechtner (a) cancer, somatic, 114500 (a); Rubinstein-Taybi syndrome 2, 613684 (a)"


 #Then following command will give nothing
  cat sample|awk '/\([0-9]\)/ { print }'
```

## Cate-II:

When there is some number inside (),:

```
cat sample
Deaf, a 603622 (s), Auto dom; 153650 (s), Autosomal dominant; Fechtner (a) cancer, somatic, 114500 (a); Rubinstein-Taybi syndrome 2, 613684 (2)"


 cat sample|awk '/\([0-9]\)/ { print }'
 Deaf, a 603622 (s), Auto dom; 153650 (s), Autosomal dominant; Fechtner (a) cancer, somatic, 114500 (2); Rubinstein-Taybi syndrome 2, 613684 (a)"
```

Comment: i need to grep based on the number inside the bracket by specifiying the field number

Comment: awk '/\([X]\)/ { print }' filename.txt , where X is the number inside ()